# mysql - find out if input exists in last 30 records

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know if the registering user's ip exist in the last 30 records. This will help me prevent multiple registrations. I have difficulty in my attempt to do this in mysql. This is where I'm at so far:

The old query that checks multiple ip's across all records:

```
$same_ip_count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login_users WHERE ip='".$ip."'"));
```

The new code that fails:

```
$same_ip_count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query(
"SELECT 'user_id'
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM login_users
    ORDER BY user_id DESC
    LIMIT 30
) AS t
WHERE t.ip = '".$ip."'"));
```

Kind of new to sql so any suggestions will be great at this point.

**EDIT:**

To be clear - I want to search only the last 30 records. I don't want to search all records and then limit them to 30.

Comment: Which error do you get ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM login_users WHERE ip='$ip' ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 30` won't work?

Comment: Let me guess... `SELECT 'user_id'` prints `user_id` several times, doesn't it?

Comment: Well it doesnt seem to me that this will always get you the "last 30" records. In order to do that you would need to ORDER by something that is sequential to the table like an auto_increment PK or a timestamp column. I doubt your `user_id` can fulfill that role because i assume there are multiple records with the same user_id in that table you are querying.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @kingkero I want to search the last 30 records not all the records and then to limit them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use a subquery to get the last 30 items. Then, you can select from that list of 30 where the IP matches.

```
Select * From
(SELECT *
        FROM login_users
        ORDER BY registration_date DESC
        LIMIT 30) a
 WHERE a.ip = '".$ip."'
```

Comment: I want to search only from the last 30 records. I don't want to search all records and then limit them to 30.

Comment: update query with order by registration_date, because order by user_id does not make any sense.

Comment: @Tom That is the only way you can get the last 30 records, as far as I know. What is wrong with this method?

Comment: This method won't work because it will only pull records that match the IP, not necessarily from the last 30 users.

Comment: @Jon Well I assumed he also wanted to match IP based on his original code

Comment: @Jon exactly... I need the last 30 records not the matching 30 records

Comment: He does, but only if it exists in the last 30 users. ^^

Comment: @Tom Then why not remove the IP clause?

Comment: limit brings you last 30 records only. I think you are confused

Comment: @SureshKamrushi I was simply confused by what the OP wanted, not how `LIMIT` works .. I've updated my answer though, that should do what he wants.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi Thanks for pointing out my countless mistakes here. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql doesn't know what are the 30 last records. If you use an auto-incrementing primary key then you can ORDER by that key in descendant order.

Comment: Ordering by the registration date imposes that the php part is correct, while ordering by an auto-incrementing primary key cannot be biased. You should read the link yes.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$query = mysql_query(
"SELECT 'user_id' as result from `login_users` WHERE ip = '".$ip."' ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 30");

$same_ip = mysql_num_rows($query);
```